# Criar trigger MySql incrementar/decrementar atributo

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Tenho as seguintes tabelas

```
-> app(id_app, nome_app)
-> category(id_category, nome_category, total_apps)
-> app_category(id_app_fk, id_category_fk)
```

Oque eu quero fazer é o seguinte, que sempre que eu adicionar dados a tabela "app_category" ele verifique quantos apps foram adicionados relacionados aquela categoria e incremente o valor+1 ao campo "total_app" na tabela "category", esse campo seria o total de apps pertencentes a cada categoria.

O mesmo deve ser feito ao ser deletado uma linha da tabela "app_category" 1 deve ser decrementado do campo "total_apps".

**Detalhes:** como podem perceber os campos da tabela app_category são chaves estrangeiras que referenciam a tabela "app" a tabela "category".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar esse par de TRIGGERS:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `count_apps_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `app_category`
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE category
    SET total_apps = total_apps + 1
    WHERE id_category = NEW.id_category_fk;


CREATE TRIGGER `count_apps_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `app_category`
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE category
    SET total_apps = total_apps - 1
    WHERE id_category = OLD.id_category_fk;
```

Em funcionamento:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60b60/1/0

Comment: Olá, eu testei seu código e sempre apresenta o seguinte erro: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''count_apps_insert' AFTER INSERT ON 'app_category' 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UP' at line 1      Já apaguei as aspas e tudo mais e sempre apresenta erro, oq estaria errado?

Comment: AlfredBaudisch seu código deu certo com as seguintes alterações, a remoção do BEGIN e do END no fim das triggers, após remover eles a trigger foi criada e como eu já testei aqui funcionou perfeitamente, edita sua resposta quando possível, vou marca-la como correta, obg.

Comment: @MarcosJunior você notou antes de eu postar a correção :D Anexei um SQLFiddle mostrando em funcionamento.